# @CacheEvict is not working in SpringBoot

Tags: spring

```
@Cacheable(value = "apis", key = "#request")
    public Object queryCenterAPI(QCRequest request,HttpHeaders headers) throws JSONException, ParseException {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ToolsResponseHandler());
        Response res=new Response();
        HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
        logger.info("No Caching^^^^^^^^^^");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String requestJson = gson.toJson(request);
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestJson, headers);
        System.out.println("Request Body "+requestEntity);

        Object response = null;
        try {
            response = restTemplate.postForObject(QCUtils.queryURL, requestEntity, Object.class);
            logger.info("1st response>"+response);

            response = response.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "");
            System.out.println("Final response "+response);

        }catch (HttpClientErrorException httpEx) {

            logger.info("Error:"+httpEx);
        }
        return response;

    } 

    @CacheEvict(value = "apis", key = "#request")
      public void resetOnRequest(QCRequest request) {
        // Intentionally blank
        System.out.println("Evict in Progrsss......");

      }
```

Caching is working fine but I am unable to use @CacheEvict annotation.I guess cacheEvict method is called immediately after Cacheable method.
The resetOnRequest() method is not called after Cachable method(queryCenterAPI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ehcache works for me andAdding the below Xml file and Config file is enough to do caching and cache evict.

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
    updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect"
    dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <cache name="apis"
        eternal="false"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" 
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
        timeToIdleSeconds="200" timeToLiveSeconds="900"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
        transactionalMode="off">
    </cache>

public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        cmfb.setShared(true);
        return cmfb;
    }
}
```

We only need to configure in xml file and give the time after which cache eviction take place.

Answer (score 12):

Cache evict method should be called from a different class otherwise it will not work, same for method with @Cacheable annotation.

Comment: True, I had to create a separate class like MyObjectInvalidator and then @CacheEvict started to work

Comment: It worked in my case too. Made a different class:           

public class EvictCache {

  @CacheEvict(key = "#Name", value = "#value")
  public void evictOldCacheByName(String Name) {
    log.info("Removing old cache");
  }

Answer (score 5):

Another different way instead the @CacheEvict annotation, would be using the CacheManager > https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html

For single value;

```
public void evictSingleCacheValue(String cacheName, String cacheKey) {
    cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).evict(cacheKey);
}
```

For all values;

```
public void evictAllCacheValues(String cacheName) {
    cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to switch to the "aspectj" mode in order for the `@CacheEvict` to work fine.

From Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotation-enable):

> The default advice mode for processing caching annotations is "proxy"
>   which allows for interception of calls through the proxy only; local
>   calls within the same class cannot get intercepted that way. For a
>   more advanced mode of interception, consider switching to "aspectj"
>   mode in combination with compile-time or load-time weaving.

Second option would be to try to move the `@CacheEvict` method into another class.